# Silex Form Choice field

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, silex

I'm using Symfony forms and Twig to create a filter but something weird is going on and I can't figure out why. I have 4 choice fields, the first 2 choice fields are returning the correct values but the last 2 choice fields are returning the same values as the second choice field.

this is the code for the Controller

```
// Create Form
    $filterForm = $app['form.factory']->createNamed('filterForm')

        // search
        ->add('title', 'text')

        // date
        ->add('dates', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $DatesForCombo,
            'placeholder' => 'Kies...',
            'required' => false))

        // category
        ->add('categories', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $CategoriesForCombo,
            'placeholder' => 'Kies...',
            'required' => false))

        // location
        ->add('locations', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $LocationsForCombo,
            'placeholder' => 'Kies...', 
            'required' => false))

        // organiser
        ->add('organisers', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $OrganisersForCombo,
            'placeholder' => 'Kies...',
            'required' => false))

        // is_gentian
        ->add('gents',null,array(
            'label' => 'Enkel Gents gesproken',
            'required' => false))

        ->add('gentsGesproken', 'checkbox', array(
            'value' => 'Y',
            'required' => false))

        // is_free
        ->add('gratis',null,array(
            'label' => 'Enkel gratis events',
            'required' => false))

        ->add('gratisEvents', 'checkbox', array(
            'value' => 'Y',
            'required' => false));
```

This is the code for the Twig Template

```
<form action="{{ path('events.index') }}" method="post"  {{ form_enctype(filterForm) }}  novalidate="novalidate" role="form">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Filter Events</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_widget(filterForm.title, { 'attr' : { 'class': 'form-control', 'name' : 'filterform[title]', 'id':'filterform_title' }} ) }}
                </div>

                <!-- filter dates -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_widget(filterForm.dates, { 'attr' : { 'class': 'form-control', 'name' : 'filterform[day]', 'id':'filterform_title' }} ) }} 
                </div>

                <!-- filter categories -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_widget(filterForm.categories, { 'attr' : { 'class': 'form-control', 'name' : 'filterform[category]', 'id':'filterform_categories' }} ) }}
                </div>

                <!-- filter location -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_widget(filterForm.locations, { 'attr' : { 'class': 'form-control', 'name' : 'filterform[location]', 'id':'locations' }} ) }}
                </div>

                <!-- filter organisers -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_widget(filterForm.organisers, { 'attr' : { 'class': 'form-control', 'name' : 'filterform[organiser]', 'id':'organisers' }} ) }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- filter chckbx Gents gesproken -->
                    <label>
                        {{ form_widget(filterForm.gentsGesproken) }}                
                        {{ form_label(filterForm.gents) }}
                    </label>
                    <!-- filter chckbx Gratis events -->
                    <label>
                        {{ form_widget(filterForm.gratisEvents) }}                 
                        {{ form_label(filterForm.gratis) }}
                    </label>
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" id="filterform__token" name="filterform[_token]" value="lJ3pQTYX8yEbYpDhmHH6V_ktwtbz_5BdWP0Fss6Z7s0" />
                <button type="submit" id="filterform_filter" name="filterform[filter]" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Filter</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

The 4 arrays used are of course different, can someone please help me?

Comment: can you add the generated HTML output?

Comment: here is the html code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qjghqhpkxfz6yhf/form.html?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, some of the html characters where not encoded correctly, even though my database was in utf8mb5_general_ci and I use UTF-8 in my templates, the characters where shown as a �. Looks like Silex Forms can't handle a choice field with a character that isn't encoded. Never thought that those 2 problems where connected but it was just a matter of using the utf8_encode() method to fill the arrays used in the choice fields. In my twig templates I used

```
// create an array for the organiser combobox...
$OrganisersForCombo = array();
$numberOfOrganisers = count($AllOrganisers);
for($i = 0 ; $i <= $numberOfOrganisers-1 ; $i++){
    $title = $AllOrganisers[$i]['title'];
    $OrganisersForCombo[$i+1] = utf8_encode($title);
}
```

In my Twig templates I used

```
{{ data|convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'ASCII') }}
```

Like so: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/convert_encoding.html